# Not able to get Previous row attributes in Html Table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have been working on this Html Table Structure :

```
<table>
    <tr id='1' pid='p3'><td><button id='1' onClick="get(this,'p3')">1</button></td></tr>
    <tr id='2' pid='p3'><td><button id='2' onClick="get(this,'p3')">2</button></td></tr>
    <tr id='3' pid='p2'><td><button id='3' onClick="get(this,'p2')">3</button></td></tr>
    <tr id='4' pid='p1'><td><button id='4' onClick="get(this,'p1')">4</button></td></tr>
    <tr id='5' pid='p2'><td><button id='5' onClick="get(this,'p2')">5</button></td></tr>
    <tr id='6' pid='p2'><td><button id='6' onClick="get(this,'p2')">6</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

My Aim is to get id of ('closest , above') table row's button on click of a button inside the current table row (Sorry thats a bit confusing)

I use jQuery as such :

```
function get(elm,pid){
    alert($.nid=$(elm).closest('tr').prev("tr[pid='"+pid+"']").find('button').attr('id'));
}
```

I found this out that if the rows are situated one above other the id of button in previous row is fetched without issues.

But if the row is further above it is not able to get the values; what is wrong in the logic? Where am I going wrong?

Please find my Explanatory fiddle Here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/jtYDP/386/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.prev()` method selects the *first* previous sibling element. If you pass a selector it selects the previous sibling only if it matches with the specified selector.

Suppose you click on the fourth button. The second parameter of the `get` function is `p1`, since the `tr` doesn't match with specified selector jQuery returns an empty collection and consequently `attr` returns `undefined`.

If I have understood the question correctly you want to select the previous `tr` that has the same `pid`. You can use `.prevAll()` and `.first()` methods.

```
$('tr button').on('click', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        pid = $row.attr('pid');

    var id = $row.prevAll("tr[pid='"+pid+"']")
                 .first() 
                 .find('button')
                 .attr('id');
});
```

**Note** that IDs must be *unique*. And `pid` is not a valid attribute. You can use `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: Is there any possible solution on this in jquery

Comment: @athon If you click on the fourth button what do you expect? What value should be alerted?

Comment: fourth button displaying undefined is ok as it does not have any previous pid's.. But if I click on fifth button id of closest previous button with same pid should be alerted. I have explained it in fiddle.

Comment: Thank You So much Vohunam.. prevAll().first() worked for me :) Soo Sorry I couldnt vote up your efforts my rep is too low to do so.. I will as soon as I can..

Comment: @athon You are very welcome, indeed! I'm glad  I was able to help.